# How to check input arguments in a python script with CLI?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse, program-entry-point

I'm writing a small script to learn Python. The script prints a chess tournament table for N players. It has a simple CLI with a single argument N. Now I'm trying the following approach:

```python
import argparse

def parse_args(argv: list[str] | None = None) -> int:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Tournament tables")
    parser.add_argument('N', help="number of players (2 at least)", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    if args.N < 2:
        parser.error("N must be 2 at least")
    return args.N

def main(n: int) -> None:
    print(F"Here will be the table for {n} players")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(parse_args())
```

But this seems to have a flaw. The function `main` doesn't check `n` for invalid input (as it's the job of CLI parser). So if somebody calls `main` directly from another module (a tester for example), he may call it with lets say 0, and the program most likely crashes.

How should I properly handle this issue?

I'm considering several possible ways, but not sure what is the best.

1. Add a proper value checking and error handling to `main`. This option looks ugly to me, as it violates the DRY principle and forces `main` to double the job of CLI.
2. Just document that `main` must take only n >= 2, and its behaviour is unpredicted otherwise. Possibly to combine with adding an assertion check to `main`, like this:

   `assert n >= 2, "n must be 2 or more"`
3. Perhaps such a function should not be external at all? So the whole chosen idiom is wrong and the script's entry point should be rewritten another way.
4. ???

Comment: I think the validation should only be in the main function, as it it a core requirement for the program. Also, I don't think the input handling should handle invalid check because it doesn't need to know about the application and how it works, it just need to pass the input to it.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I always believed that data validation should be an essential part of CLI. Anyway argparse casts the data to certain types, so it already performs at least a part of data validation, preventing input of 0.5 for int value, for example.

Comment: Normally `argparse` is used to parse commandline inputs, so it's used when the module is run as a script.  In other words it's invoked via the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.  The parser may be defined in a function in the body, and thus imported, but it normally isn't used via the import.  The primary purpose of a parser is to determine what the user wants.  There's no hard-and-fast rule for deciding what error checking is done by 1)  the parser itself,  2) immediately after parsing, or 3) in functions that use its values.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get it. What is meant "normally isn't used via the import" ? Regardless of the location of the parser, I still has to write "import argparse" to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have `main` do all the checking aind raise `ArgumentError` if something is amiss. Then catch that exception and forward it to the parser for display. Something along these lines:

```
import argparse

def run_with_args(argv: list[str] | None = None) -> int:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Tournament tables")
    parser.add_argument('N', help="number of players (2 at least)", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    try:
        main(args.N)
    except argparse.ArgumentError as ex:
        parser.error(str(ex))

def main(n: int) -> None:
    if N < 2:
        raise argparse.ArgumentError("N must be 2 at least")
    print(F"Here will be the table for {n} players")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_with_args()
```

If you don't want to expose `argparse.ArgumentError` to library users of `main`, you can also create a custom exception type instead of it.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. Your answer definitely solves my issue, I just need a time to compare it with others. The only problem is that I really want to encapsulate argparse inside of this module. But as you pointed, it can be solved with a custom exception.

Answer (score 1):

A common way of running argparse when wanting to test functions/CLI is to have the `main` function take a the `sys.argv` list and then call `parse_args` from within `main` like so:

*arg.py*

```py
import argparse

def parse_args(argv: list[str] | None = None) -> int:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Tournament tables", prog="prog")
    parser.add_argument("N", help="number of players (2 at least)", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    if args.N < 2:
        parser.error("N must be 2 at least")
    return args

def main(argv: list[str] | None = None) -> None:
    args = parse_args(argv)
    print(f"Here will be the table for {args.N} players")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This way a test can call main with a hypothetical CLI:

*test_main.py*

```py
import pytest
from arg import main

def test_main(capsys):
    with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
        main(["0"])
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert err.splitlines()[-1] == "prog: error: N must be 2 at least"
```

Comment: Thank you, Alex. Your answer solves my problem too. I'm only in doubts as it could prevent the tester from ability to test the "pure" logic of making the table (without influence of CLI), as this part is merged now with argument parsing inside of main(). The approach of Thomas' answer above seems a bit more flexible as it allows to separately test both pure CLI and pure application logic.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been using [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/) liberally for enforcing data typing at runtime, *within my code* itself.  Your N>=2 is easily enforced with a validator.

It’s a very robust, extremely widely used, library and very fast as it’s more of a data ingestion validator than a type checker.

And you could write the call as follows.  How you call main is entirely up to you: direct call, argparse, click…

```
class ParamChecker(BaseModel):
    n : int

    @validator('n')
    def n2(cls, v):
        if v <2:
            raise ValueError('must be 2+')
        return v

def main(n: int) -> None:
    params = ParamChecker(**locals())
```

Pydantic also gets you informative, if not really end user friendly, error messages.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at Pydantic. But normally I strive to minimize external dependencies and call for heavy weapons only if necessary. I guess the tiny and simple script in my case would rather stick to standard library.